# Reapplication for Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals

I would like to reapply for my parents visas who were rejected for **Belgium** with below stated reason:

1. Insufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the intended stay and for the return to their country of origin or residence, or for the transit to a third country where you will be admitted with certainty, or to be in the position to acquire such means lawfully
2. Coverage is inadmissible: the guarantor does not have an unlimited residence in Belgium.
3. No or insufficient evidence of financial coverage for the stay
4. Insufficient financial resources to the submitted bank account to fund the travel and accommodation
5. Your intention to leave the territory of the Member State before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained

I had submitted all necessary documents as mentioned in their website. Kindly advise if reapplying for same country - **Belgium** helps or can I apply as a tourist for other Schengen countries such as Switzerland/France rather than as a family visit as done by me previously by submitting commune invitation.

Comment: We have several questions regarding Schengen visa refusals and the best strategy to deal with them, you might want to look them up.

Comment: I am a bit surprised by some of the reasons, especially reason 2. Is that the wording you got on the official refusal letter?

Comment: For reson 2, I too am a bit surprised.As its a known fact I am on an official assignment until April 2016.I have a rented accomodation till that period so a commune invitation as well as my rent aggreement was submitted  along with the applications.

Answer (score 2):

Reapplying to the same country can help but it's not likely to bring much if you don't address the underlying concerns. And given the number of motives raised to justify the refusal, it seems this application had very serious deficiencies so I doubt your parents will succeed.

There is nothing that would stop your parents from applying to another country either but remember that all Schengen consulates have access to the same database and know that they just applied to Belgium. If the application is less than stellar, trying again immediately with a completely different story will make them look desperate to get a visa and not genuine about their intent.

The best way to get a visa in your parents' case is to wait a bit and improve their financial situations in the meantime. It's easier said than done of course but anything else is unlikely to succeed and could even backfire by damaging their credibility.